# Using PHP ftp_get() to retrieve file with wildcard filename

Tags: php, ftp, filenames, wildcard, glob

I have a file on an FTP with a dynamic filename. The schema looks something like:

```
ABCD_2_EFGH_YYMMDD_YYMMDD_randomnumber_.TXT
```

The dates (`YYMMDD`) reflect the previous day and current day and the `randomnumber` value is a count of the records in the file and varies each day.

I am attempting to retrieve the file using PHP but I am having trouble using a wildcard name. Here is a sample of the code:

```
<?php
$yesterday = strtotime('-1 day', time());
$today = strtotime('-0 day', time());
$local_file = "ABCD_2_EFGH__".date('Y-m-j', $yesterday).".txt";
$server_file = "ABCD_2_EFGH_".date('ymd', $yesterday)."_".date('ymd', $today)."_*.txt";

$conn_id = ftp_connect(ftpaddress);
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, 'username', 'password');
ftp_chdir($conn_id, 'subdirectory name');
ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY);
?>
```

When running this code i get the following error:

> ftp_get() expects parameter 3 to be a valid path

I have also tried using `glob()` for `$server_file` and receive the same error.

Does anyone know how to use dynamic filenames with `ftp_get()`?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ftp_nlist` with pattern to retreive file names from ftp folder. And then use `ftp_get` in loop

```
$fileList = ftp_nlist($conn_id, 'subdirectory_name/file_prefix_*.txt');

for ($i = 0; $i < count($fileList); $i++) {
    $localFile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'ftp_in');
    if (ftp_get($conn_id, $localFile, $fileList[$i], FTP_BINARY)){
      //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ftp_get` can be used to download a single file only. No wildcards are supported.

---

The only reliable way is to list all files, filter them locally and then download them one-by-one:

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect("ftp.example.com") or die("Cannot connect");
ftp_login($conn_id, "username", "password") or die("Cannot login");
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true) or die("Cannot change to passive mode");

$files = ftp_nlist($conn_id, "/path");

foreach ($files as $file)
{
    if (preg_match("/\.txt$/i", $file))
    {
        echo "Found $file\n";
        // download with ftp_get
    }
}
```

Some (most) servers will allow you to use a wildcard directly:

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect("ftp.example.com") or die("Cannot connect");
ftp_login($conn_id, "username", "password") or die("Cannot login");
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true) or die("Cannot change to passive mode");

$files = ftp_nlist($conn_id, "/path/*.txt");

foreach ($files as $file)
{
    echo "Found $file\n";
    // download with ftp_get
}
```

But that's a nonstandard feature (while widely supported).

For details see my answer to [FTP directory partial listing with wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9282753/850848#28187442).