# Batch file to download a file with name that starts with a given string from FTP

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I use the following bat file:

```
::@echo off
cd /d %0\.. 
set cmd=%CD%

echo user %~2> %cmd%\ftpcmd.dat
echo %~3>> %cmd%\ftpcmd.dat
echo bin>> %cmd%\ftpcmd.dat
IF NOT "%5" == "" echo cd %~5>> %cmd%\ftpcmd.dat
echo get %~4 %cmd%\%~4>> %cmd%\ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> %cmd%\ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:%cmd%\ftpcmd.dat %1
del %cmd%\ftpcmd.dat
```

Parameters and executions are like below:

```
c:\download.bat  ftpHost login password file.xml FTP_FOLDER
```

As you can see this script copy file with the specific name.

How can I change this script to look for the first XML file that starts with a certain string. So instead of `file.xml` I want pass `beginning_of_the_string` (without `.xml`). Then script should copy the first of these files?

Answer (score 1):

The Windows `ftp.exe` does not support wildcards on it own. Though if you use a wildcard in `mget` command, it will pass it unmodified to the server. If the server supports wildcards (what is a non-standard, but common behaviour), it will allow `ftp.exe` to download only the matching files. See also [FTP directory partial listing with wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9282753/850848#28187442).

```
mget beginning_of_the_string*.xml
```

---

If your FTP server does not support wilcards, you can run the `ftp.exe` in two phases. First to list the remote directory. Then you locally process the list to find a file with given prefix. And then run the `ftp.exe` again to download the file. Check the answer by @Hackoo for an example of such implementation.

---

Or use another FTP client that supports wildcard matching locally.

E.g. with [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/) you can do:

```
@echo off
cd /d %0\.. 
set cmd=%CD%

echo open ftp://%~2:%~3@%1 > %cmd%\ftpcmd.dat
IF NOT "%5" == "" echo cd %~5 >> %cmd%\ftpcmd.dat
echo get %~4 %cmd%\ >> %cmd%\ftpcmd.dat
echo exit >> %cmd%\ftpcmd.dat
%cmd%\winscp.com /script=%cmd%\ftpcmd.dat
del %cmd%\ftpcmd.dat
```

And you call it like:

```
c:\download.bat ftpHost login password beginning_of_the_string*.xml FTP_FOLDER
```

Instead of the `beginning_of_the_string*.xml`, use any other [file mask/wildcard that WinSCP supports](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask).

For details, see the guide to [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Answer (score 1):

As **Martin Prikryl** said :

> You can run the ftp.exe in two phases. First to list the remote
>   directory. Then you locally process the list to find a file with given
>   prefix. And then run the ftp.exe again to download the file.

So you can give a try for this batch that can download from a public **FTP Server :
ftp.microsoft.com** all **ws*.doc** files that start with this string **ws** as example :

```
@echo off
mode con cols=85 lines=22 & Color A
::***********************************
Set FTPSERVER=ftp.microsoft.com
Title List files and folders on an FTP server (%FTPSERVER%) by Hackoo
Set USER=anonymous
Set Password=anonymous@anonymous.com
Set DossierFTP=/bussys/winsock/winsock2/
Set DownloadFolder=winsock2
Set BeginString=ws
Set ExtensionType=doc
::*******************************************************
Goto List
:List
> ft.do echo Open %FTPSERVER%
>> ft.do echo %USER%
>> ft.do echo %Password%
>> ft.do echo prompt n
>> ft.do echo bin
>> ft.do echo cd %DossierFTP%
>> ft.do echo ls -R TLIST.txt
>> ft.do echo bye
ftp -s:ft.do
del ft.do
CLS
Color 9B
echo Click to Download the files list
pause
Goto Download
::*********************************************************
:Download
Cls
> ft.do echo Open %FTPSERVER%
>> ft.do echo %USER%
>> ft.do echo %Password%
>> ft.do echo prompt n
>> ft.do echo bin
>> ft.do echo cd %DossierFTP%
findstr /r /i "%ExtensionType%" TLIST.txt > %ExtensionType%Files.txt
findstr /r /i "^%BeginString%" %ExtensionType%Files.txt > %ExtensionType%.txt
for /F %%f in (%ExtensionType%.txt) do ( >> ft.do echo get %%f) 
>> ft.do echo bye
ftp -s:ft.do
del ft.do
CLS
Color 9A
echo Moving downloaded files to %DownloadFolder% Folder
pause
Goto MoveFiles
::*********************************************************
:MoveFiles
cls
echo Moving downloaded files to %DownloadFolder% Folder
Set Source=%~dp0
Set Destination=%Source%%DownloadFolder%
if not exist %DownloadFolder% MD %DownloadFolder%
for /F %%f in (%ExtensionType%.txt) do (move "%Source%%%f" "%Destination%")
pause
```