# How to write command in windows batch file to copy a zip file from an FTP path to a local folder in my computer

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp

I want to copy a zip file from an FTP path to a local folder in my computer.

My client previously used ***coreftp.exe*** for that purpose. But now he ask us to use ***ftp.exe*** [default in windows machine, available at *C:\Windows\System32\ftp.exe*] for that purpose. The ftp is in the format :

```
ftp://username@ftpserver.address.com
```

And want to download it to **d:\sample\docs** folder on my machine.

I want that in a batch file so that I can schedule it through windows task manager.

So could you please help me to write that command on the batch file.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Would you consider using a free tool that supports FTP as well - its called [SyncBack][1]. With it, you can set a scheduled task and connect to FTP with a nice graphic interface. Way better than using scripts if you ask me.


  [1]: http://www.2brightsparks.com/download-syncbackfree.html

Comment: But my client specifically told me to use the default ftp.exe. So could you please help me with that.

Comment: Okay, try out this [ftp via command prompt tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/how-to-automate-ftp-uploads-from-the-windows-command-line/)

Comment: You can also take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29700524/batch-file-to-download-a-file-with-name-that-starts-with-a-given-string-from-ftp/29711953#29711953

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FTP.EXE is capable of executing script files. So you could just put this into your bat file:

```
@ECHO OFF
CD d:\sample\docs
FTP -v -i -s:C:\some\path\ftpscript.txt
```

And something like this into your ftpscript.txt:

```
open ftp://ftpserver.address.com
username
password
cd myfolder
get some_zip_file.zip
disconnect
bye
```

This will download some_zip_file.zip into the current directory (`d:\sample\docs`).

Comment: cd myfolder in the txt file is correct?  or there i have 2 write CD d:\sample\docs.. becoz I have tried both but they r not working

Comment: CD in the bat will determin where to save the downloaded file. CD in the txt is the command to change the diractory on the FTP server. In case the file is in the root directory of the FTP server you can just skip it.

Comment: If you have trouble with the FTP script you can just open CMD, type FTP and then enter the content of yout script file line by line. This way you can check which lines work for you and which don't.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried that. All success till I write put d:\sample\docs on the cmd. Pls note that I have full access over that folder.So any thoughts.