# Copy multiple files from FTP based on string to local through bat

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I want to get one or many files from a source ftp site.  I only want to get the files that have a constant prefix ("ORDER").  I will later import these files into my db, but for right now, I just want to copy these specified files to my local directory ("c:\Destination").

I have tried this...

```
    open ftp.[address]
    [username]
    [password]
    cd \SubFolder
    for %%I in (ORDER*.txt) do copy %%I c:\Destination\
    quit
```

But nothing apparently happens(??).  I am able to hardcode for a single file with a static name.  but using the variable for multiple files is not working for me.  I have used "copy", "xcopy" and "get" in the "do" command, but none appear to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to mix up an `ftp` script and a batch file, but these are separate things...

Comment: Use `mget` command as in `order*`. Make sure `glob` is on.

Comment: @aschipfi  I save the file as a .bat, so I figured it was a batch file (I am clearly a novice in command line).  I use similar code elsewhere to pick up statically named files in other FTP sites, so I used that as a starting point.  But these files will be dynamically named with the "ORDER" prefix.

Comment: @Noodles  I tried "mget" in place of "copy" in my above code and still no luck.  I played with the glob setting as well, and it looks like it is "on" by default.

Comment: It is a text file with FTP commands. Not a batch file. You can call it anything you want. So `ftp -A -i speedtest.tele2.net` then `mget *KB.zip`. Unix servers are case sensitive. Your firewall may block standard FTP. Use PASV mode which Windows' FTP can't do. See `ftp /?`.

Comment: See [Batch file to download a file with name that starts with a given string from FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29700524/850848#29701443).