# Download files from an FTP server containing given string using Python

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I'm trying to download a large number of files that all share a common string (`DEM`) from an FTP sever. These files are nested inside multiple directories. For example, `Adair/DEM*`  and `Adams/DEM*`

The FTP sever is located here: `ftp://ftp.igsb.uiowa.edu/gis_library/counties/` and requires no username and password. 
So, I'd like to go through each county and download the files containing the string `DEM`.

I've read many questions here on Stack Overflow and the documentation from Python, but cannot figure out how to use `ftplib.FTP()` to get into the site without a username and password (which is not required), and I can't figure out how to grep or use `glob.glob` inside of ftplib or urllib.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, seems to work. There may be issues if trying to download a directory, or scan a file. Exception handling may come handy to trap wrong filetypes and skip.

`glob.glob` cannot work since you're on a remote filesystem, but you can use `fnmatch` to match the names

Here's the code: it download all files matching `*DEM*` in TEMP directory, sorting by directory.

```
import ftplib,sys,fnmatch,os

output_root = os.getenv("TEMP")

fc = ftplib.FTP("ftp.igsb.uiowa.edu")
fc.login()
fc.cwd("/gis_library/counties")

root_dirs = fc.nlst()
for l in root_dirs:
    sys.stderr.write(l + " ...\n")
    #print(fc.size(l))
    dir_files = fc.nlst(l)
    local_dir = os.path.join(output_root,l)
    if not os.path.exists(local_dir):
        os.mkdir(local_dir)

    for f in dir_files:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(f,"*DEM*"):   # cannot use glob.glob
            sys.stderr.write("downloading "+l+"/"+f+" ...\n")
            local_filename = os.path.join(local_dir,f)
            with open(local_filename, 'wb') as fh:
                fc.retrbinary('RETR '+ l + "/" + f, fh.write)

fc.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

The [answer by @Jean](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38943398/850848#38943548) with the local pattern matching is the correct portable solution adhering to FTP standards.

Though as [most FTP servers do support non-standard wildcard use with file listing commands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9282753/850848#28187442), you can almost always use a simpler and mainly more efficient solution like:

```
files = ftp.nlst("*DEM*")
for f in files:
    with open(f, 'wb') as fh:
        ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + f, fh.write)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`fsspec`](https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)s [`FTPFileSystem`](https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#fsspec.implementations.ftp.FTPFileSystem) for convenient globbing on an FTP server:

```
import fsspec.implementations.ftp
ftpfs = fsspec.implementations.ftp.FTPFileSystem("ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov")
files = ftpfs.glob("/pub/data/swdi/stormevents/csvfiles/*1985*")
print(files)
contents = ftpfs.cat(files[0])
print(contents[:100])
```

Result:

```
['/pub/data/swdi/stormevents/csvfiles/StormEvents_details-ftp_v1.0_d1985_c20160223.csv.gz', '/pub/data/swdi/stormevents/csvfiles/StormEvents_fatalities-ftp_v1.0_d1985_c20160223.csv.gz', '/pub/data/swdi/stormevents/csvfiles/StormEvents_locations-ftp_v1.0_d1985_c20160223.csv.gz']
b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x08\xcb\xd8\xccV\x00\x03StormEvents_details-ftp_v1.0_d1985_c20160223.csv\x00\xd4\xfd[\x93\x1c;r\xe7\x8b\xbe\x9fOA\xe3\xd39f\xb1h\x81[\\\xf8\x16U\x95\xac\xca\xc5\xacL*3\x8b\xd5\xd4\x8bL\xd2\xb4\x9d'
```

A nested search also works, for example, `nested_files = ftpfs.glob("/pub/data/swdi/stormevents/**1985*")`, but it can be quite slow.