# How to get list of files based on pattern matching using FTP?

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

I need to get a list of files from an FTP server.

The FTP server has over 10, 000 files.

I only need the files that start with `ABC...` (which is like 10 files).
But new files get added every 10 minutes.

So I only need to get the files that start with `ABC` that have been created in the last 10 minutes.

How do I achieve this? Can I do this from C# natively?

What I have seen so far, I can connect to the FTP server, get a list of ALL the files and check the name of each one... this seems like it would take a long time if the number of files increases...

Ta

Comment: if i was you i would have a little console application sitting somewhere which keeps calling the FTP server every 10 minutes and updates a JSON file or even a database with the file names. This means you can query the JSON file or database without worrying about speed via your application. This is the approach i have done for many problems like the above. Yes everything you said above is very possible with c# and would not be complex to do.. give me a shout if you need a hand or have any code to show!

Comment: Josh - Thank you so much... I appreciate your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, there's no other way than the one you know: retrieve list of all files and filter them locally.

---

But many servers support non-standard/proprietary filtering of the listing.

If you are lucky and your FTP server do support this, you can use a file mask to retrieve only a subset of files. In your case the mask would by usually like `ABC*`. Most major FTP servers do support `*` pattern.

```
FtpWebRequest request =
    (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/path/ABC*");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");  
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
```

---

For a partial list of supported patterns of common FTP servers, see my answer to [FTP directory partial listing with wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9282753/850848#28187442).