# Listing files on FTP server using PHP glob is not working

Tags: php, ftp

I use this code to access directory.

```
$location = 'files/';
$pictures = glob($location . "*.png");
```

I want to access remote path using FTP

```
$location = opendir('ftp://user:password@host_name/files');
$pictures = glob($location . "*.png");
```

My FTP directory access code not work correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[PHP `glob` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) does not support URL wrappers:

> Note: This function will not work on [remote files](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php) as the file to be examined must be accessible via the server's filesystem.

---

The only reliable way is to list files matching a wildcard, is to list all files using PHP FTP functions and filter them locally:

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect("ftp.example.com") or die("Cannot connect");
ftp_login($conn_id, "username", "password") or die("Cannot login");
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true) or die("Cannot change to passive mode");

$files = ftp_nlist($conn_id, "/path");

foreach ($files as $file)
{
    if (preg_match("/\.png$/i", $file))
    {
        echo "Found $file\n";
    }
}
```

*(this is what the `glob` would do internally anyway, had it supported URL wrappers)*

---

Some (most) FTP servers will allow you to use a wildcard directly:

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect("ftp.example.com") or die("Cannot connect");
ftp_login($conn_id, "username", "password") or die("Cannot login");
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true) or die("Cannot change to passive mode");

$files = ftp_nlist($conn_id, "/path/*.png");

foreach ($files as $file)
{
    echo "Found $file\n";
}
```

But that's a nonstandard feature (while widely supported).

For details see my answer to [FTP directory partial listing with wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9282753/850848#28187442).