# Retrieve newest file with a specific extension from FTP in PHP

Tags: php, ftp, zip

I'm trying to get the latest file with a specific extension from a folder via FTP.
I'm using the following code to get the most recent file. But it gets the most recent file regardless of file extension.

```
// new connect

$conn = ftp_connect('ftp.website.com');
ftp_login($conn, 'username', 'password');

// get list of files on given path
$files = ftp_nlist($conn, '/data');

$mostRecent = array(
    'time' =\> 0,
    'file' =\> null
);

foreach ($files as $file) {
    // get the last modified time for the file
    $time = ftp_mdtm($conn, $file);

    if ($time > $mostRecent['time']) {
        // this file is the most recent so far
        $mostRecent['time'] = $time;
        $mostRecent['file'] = $file;
    }
}

ftp_get($conn, "/home/mywebsite/public_html/wp-content/uploads/data-zipped/target.zip", $mostRecent\['file'\], FTP_BINARY);
ftp_delete($conn, $mostRecent\['file'\]);
ftp_close($conn);
```

I would like to get specific files with specific extensions.

The files I want to get end with the following `filename.add.zip`. The filename changes daily. So it could be `file22.add.zip` `moredata.add.zip`. But the `add.zip` remains the same.

Unfortunately there are also files with the extension `filename.del.zip`. So it can't just be .zip it needs to be `add.zip`.

So via FTP, I want to pickup the most recent file ending in `add.zip`.

Anyone have a solution? The code that I currently us only picks up the most recent file. Regardless of the file extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check for files that ends with `*.add.zip`, add a filter in your loops:

```php
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $time = ftp_mdtm($conn, $file);

    // get last 8 characters from the filename
    $fileSuffix = substr($file, -8);

    if ($time > $mostRecent['time'] && $fileSuffix == '.add.zip') {
        $mostRecent['time'] = $time;
        $mostRecent['file'] = $file;
    }
}

var_dump($mostRecent);
```

Comment: That works. But you definitely want to first filter the files by extension and only then query the remote server for the timestamp of the filtered files!

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the good universal answer by @Anggara, many (most) FTP servers will simply allow you to retrieve listing filtered by the extension:

```
$files = ftp_nlist($conn, '/data/*.add.zip');
```

Some references:

- [FTP directory partial listing with wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9282753/850848)
- [Listing files on FTP server using PHP glob is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48949352/850848)

---

Btw, if you have lots of files, calling `php_mdtm` for each of them might take ages. See also [How to get last modified text files by date from remote FTP location](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29147534/850848).

Comment: This solution is much better, since you don't have to list other files that does not match the pattern and will reduce the loop.